# Использование регулярных выражений python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Забыл и не могу найти как сделать:

1. допустим мне с объектом надо провернуть определенный набор действий

   ```
   a = [fun1, fun2 ...]
   for i in a:
       classobject.(и здесь нужно сделать чтобы подставлялись функции)
   ```
2. и если надо выполнить одинаковое действие с большим количеством похожих обьектов

   ```
   for i in range(N):
       classobject(а здесь чтоб подставлялась цифра).func()
   ```

или может посоветуете что то более продуманное, заранее спасибо

Comment: И причем здесь регулярные выражения?

Comment: Если Вам это требуется, то с большой вероятностью в архитектуре Вашего приложения что-то не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Вызов метода по имени:

   ```py
   getattr(obj, 'method_name')()
   ```
2. Получение объекта по имени:

   ```py
   globals()['obj']
   ```

   или:

   ```py
   locals()['obj']
   ```

   Зависит от необходимой области видимости

---

***Пример:***

```
class Bacon:
    def f(self):
        print('Ni!')

    def g(self):
        print('eggs')


obj_0 = Bacon()
obj_1 = Bacon()

method_names = ['f', 'g']
for method_name in method_names:
    getattr(obj_0, method_name)()

for i in range(2):
    globals()[f'obj_{i}'].f()  # or locals()
```

***stdout:***

```html
Ni!
eggs
Ni!
Ni!
```